# match regular expression where string to match is build from variables

Tags: python, regex

I am having a problem. I am trying to match only the 2nd file.

ERIC_KM_NOW_SYSTEMIC_17001900_data.html

ERIC_KM_NOW_17001900_data.html

```
import re
viewTag = "KM_NOW"
regex = re.escape(viewTag) + r'(\d{8})' + re.escape('_data')
test = re.search(regex, "ERIC_KM_NOW_17001900_data.html")
print(test)
```

is that not correct?
I get type 'None'

Comment: your missing the underscore before the digits

Answer (score 3):

You forgot a `_` after `KM_NOW`.

(Hint: `print(regex)` to see it easily next time. ;-))